# enabling validator after control load

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a user control that contains a text box and an asp validator

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vcRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox" ErrorMessage="This field is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and this is the .cs part:

```
public partial class CMSTemplates_MyTextBoxNote : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private bool _vRequired;

    public bool ValidateRequired {
        get {
            return _vRequired;
        }
        set {
            _vRequired = value;
            vcRequired.Enabled = _vRequired;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

So when i load the control if the validator is enabled by default it works fine. But if it is disabled by default (as sown in this example) and enabled afterwords, although i can see from the debugger that the vcRequried.Enable is set to true, its doesn't work. What am i missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know but maybe because of the implementation mechanism of asp.net validators rely heavily on javascript, maybe the values doesn't change on the clientside, that's why the validation goes through, one thing you could check for is that the page does a postback when you enable the validator.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think you
     also you need to set ValidateRequired = "true" your controller

```
<uc:myCtrlr  ValidateRequired = "true"... />
```

and code behind I am not sure of this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     vcRequired.Enabled = _vRequired;
 }
```